# Adding specific numbers from one sequence to another

Tags: c#, sequence

I feel like this task should not be done this way...

My `sequenceY` length is not equal to number of steam numbers because you can't assign int[] length with int that have 0 as a starting value.
Therefore my `sequenceY` have a lot of 0 inside and I can't print the whole sequence. I even tried adding this after for loop:

```
sequenceY = new int[steamnumbercounter];
```

But it didn't work ... Why ?

My other question is how do programmers deal with sequences that have unknown length?

I managed to print only steam numbers but the task says print `sequenceY` not only part of it.

```
// 4. sequenceX[20] is made of random numbers from 1 to 30 , 
// sequenceY is made of steam numbers from sequenceX. Print sequneceY.

int[] nizx = new int[20];
int[] nizy = new int[20];
int n = 0;
int steamnumbercounter = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < nizx.Length; i++)
{
    nizx[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);
    if (nizx[i]%2==0)
    {
        nizy[n] = nizx[i];
        n++;
        steamnumbercounter++;
    }

    Console.Write("{0} , ", nizx[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < steamnumbercounter; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , ",nizy[i]);
}
```

Comment: Use System.Collections.Generic.List instead array for nizy.

Comment: Yep i thought that too  , but since those tasks are for my classes and we haven't studied lists yet i don't think i should use list here .

Comment: So what have you learned that you can use for now? Arrays, strings ?

Comment: Yep arrays , strings , and loops .

Comment: In that case, you can create a 'fake' list by concatanating the values you need in a string, seperated by commas. The string.Split(',') will give you the resulting array that you need.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not familiar with the string.Split so i can't do it your way . Although thanks for trying to help .

Comment: It is useless to have both `n` and `steamnumbercounter` as they will always be the same... Otherwise, the code would be correct. However, you might use `Array.Copy` at the end to make a copy of the appropriate size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial code review along with an answer.

> But it didn't work ... Why ?

That code didn't work because you're *reassigning* `sequenceY` to a *completely new* value.

> My other question is how do programmers deal with sequences that have unknown length?

So, with that known we can do a few things here: create an array and use `Array.Resize`, use a `List<T>`, fill the initial array then swap it for one of the right size which is filled.

I'm going to assume a "steam" number is an even one.

Your naming is not good: `nizx` and `nizy` don't convey the meaning or line up with the problem.

I'm going to demonstrate the last option (since you stated that you don't know how to use many of the *moderately* complex parts of .NET in this class yet, which is fine): fill the initial array and swap it for a new one. This will run in `O(n^2)` time (sorta).

---

So, let's start with our source array.

```
int[] sequenceX = new int[20];
```

Next we'll define our destination array *to be the same size* as our source array. (This is the maximum number of values that could be stored in it, we'll shrink it later.)

```
int[] sequenceY = new int[sequenceX.Length];
```

Then we need a variable to hold how many numbers we found that meet our criteria:

```
int steamNumbers = 0;
```

And lastly, our `Random`.

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Then, we look through all our `sequenceX` as you did, but we'll update the logic a bit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sequenceX.Length; i++)
{
    sequenceX[i] = random.Next(1, 30);

    if (sequenceX[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        sequenceY[steamNumbers] = sequenceX[i];
        steamNumbers++;
    }
}
```

So our code looks *almost* the same as yours, but we have one more thing to do: since you *only* want `sequenceY` to contain `steamNumbers` we have to shrink it or something.

```
int[] tempSequenceY = sequenceY;
sequenceY = new int[steamNumbers];

for (int i = 0; i < steamNumbers; i++)
{
    sequenceY[i] = tempSequenceY[i];
}
```

Now `sequenceY` only has your steam numbers in it.

Final code:

```
int[] sequenceX = new int[20];
int[] sequenceY = new int[sequenceX.Length];
int steamNumbers = 0;
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < sequenceX.Length; i++)
{
    sequenceX[i] = random.Next(1, 30);

    if (sequenceX[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        sequenceY[steamNumbers] = sequenceX[i];
        steamNumbers++;
    }
}

int[] tempSequenceY = sequenceY;
sequenceY = new int[steamNumbers];

for (int i = 0; i < steamNumbers; i++)
{
    sequenceY[i] = tempSequenceY[i];
}

// Print your `sequenceY` here.
```

---

You could extract this to a method pretty easily as well:

```
public int[] GetSteamNumbers(int sequenceCount, int randomMinimum, int randomMaximum)
{
    int[] sequenceX = new int[sequenceCount];
    int[] sequenceY = new int[sequenceX.Length];
    int steamNumbers = 0;
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < sequenceX.Length; i++)
    {
        sequenceX[i] = random.Next(randomMinimum, randomMaximum);

        if (sequenceX[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            sequenceY[steamNumbers] = sequenceX[i];
            steamNumbers++;
        }
    }

    int[] tempSequenceY = sequenceY;
    sequenceY = new int[steamNumbers];

    for (int i = 0; i < steamNumbers; i++)
    {
        sequenceY[i] = tempSequenceY[i];
    }

    return sequenceY;
}
```

And then call it with:

```
int[] steamNumbers = GetSteamNumbers(20, 1, 30);
```

---

Of course, for the more advanced users (this doesn't help *you*, but it may help others) we can do something as follows using LINQ:

```
var random = new Random();
var sequenceY = Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
                          .Select(x => random.Next(1, 30))
                          .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                          .ToArray();
```

Which should have the same effect. (Just demonstrating that there are still things in C# to look forward to in the future.)

Disclaimer: I wrote this entire answer outside of the IDE and without actually compiling it, I make no guarantees to the accuracy of the code but the procedure itself should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for helping me I really appreciate it . :)

Comment: Thanks for the lambda! and very detailed post. This covers everything!

Answer (score 2):

The thing with arrays in C# is that they are of fixed size.
You'll have to iterate through and re-create it or use a IEnumerable that has dynamic sizes, such as Lists.

Solution here would be to use a List that contains your integers and then you would use nizx.Add(rnd.Next(1, 30));

Comment: While *technically* they're of a fixed size, you can use `Array.Resize` to *un-fix* the size of them (which secretly creates a new array and copies the relevant parts of the old one to it, but that's more technicalities).

Comment: exactly :D! still, the Resize means calculating the size! it's not dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment above: You can create a 'fake' list by concatenating the values you need in a string, separated by commas. The string.Split(',') will give you the resulting array that you need.

Given a string of form "a,b,c,d" string.Split(',') will create the array ["a","b,"c","d"]. The code:

```
    {
        int[] nizx = new int[20];
        string numberString = string.Empty;
        int n = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < nizx.Length; i++)
        {
            nizx[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);
            if (nizx[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                numberString += nizx[i] + ",";
                n++;
            }
        }

        var numberArray = numberString.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} , ", numberArray[i]);
        }
    }
```